# How to make installer for a program include java and sql database?

Tags: java, installation

I have wrote a program with using Netbeans and Java language. This program uses sql database. Now I want to create an installer for it that users only install it and starting use it. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow,use this for asking question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using install4j, it comes with many useful features like scripting, service for windows, conguration ...

http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html

Also you can experimenting on `izpack`. But i would suggest install4j as i have good experience with install4j. 
http://java-source.net/open-source/installer-generators/izpack

Comment: Updated exisiting post.

Comment: install4j can support the sql database?